# Change iframe source when dark mode is enabled and change it back when dark mode is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, darkmode

**GOAL**: I would like to change the source of an iFrame when `onclick="toggleDarkMode()` is activated and change it back when `onclick="toggleDarkMode()` is disabled.

**PROBLEM**: My current "Dark Mode" button only changes the iFrame source once, when `onclick="toggleDarkMode()` is activated to "//www.twitch.tv/embed/yaydank/chat?parent=icelz.s3.amazonaws.com&darkpopout". Then when I click it again it doesn't change the source back to "//www.twitch.tv/embed/yaydank/chat?parent=icelz.s3.amazonaws.com&popout". If anybody could help me sort this out, I would highly appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

My current default iframe code when the page is loaded:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src="//www.twitch.tv/embed/yaydank/chat?parent=icelz.s3.amazonaws.com&popout" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

My current javascript code, which changes the source of the iframe when `onclick="toggleDarkMode()` is activated:

```
<script>
function myFunctionDark() {
    document.getElementById("myFrame").src = "//www.twitch.tv/embed/yaydank/chat?parent=icelz.s3.amazonaws.com&darkpopout";

}
</script>
```

This is my current "Dark Mode" button, which triggers "toggleDarkMode" and "myFunctionDark" function:

```
<i class="material-icons dropdown-toggle" onclick="toggleDarkMode();myFunctionDark()" data-tooltip="Dark Mode" data-tooltip-pos="left">wb_sunny</i>
```

**[LIVE LINK WHERE THE PROBLEM IS PRESENT](https://icelz.s3.amazonaws.com/twitchchathelp.html)** ("Dark Mode" button is at the top right corner")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always executing myFunctionDark() and it only set the chat dark. Try setting a condition inside like this:

```
function myFunctionDark() {
  if($(".app-container").hasClass("dark")) {
    document.getElementById("myFrame").src = "//www.twitch.tv/embed/yaydank/chat?parent=icelz.s3.amazonaws.com&darkpopout";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myFrame").src = "//www.twitch.tv/embed/yaydank/chat?parent=icelz.s3.amazonaws.com&popout";
  }
}
```